# boolean property in YAML object doesn't remain a boolean

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline with multiple stages, and each stage has a common option. I want to control that option for each stage individually, but also have a way to force it off for all stages. The YAML looks roughly like this:

```
parameters:
  -name: globalFlag
   type: boolean
   default: true

  -name: stageSettings
    type: object
    default:
      - stageName: stageOne
        stageFlag: true
      - stageName: stageTwo
        stageFlag: false

...

stages
  - ${{each stageDef in parameters.stageSettings }}:
    ...
    myFlag: ${{ and(parameters.globalFlag, stageDef.stageFlag) }}
```

That almost works, except I believe `stageDef.stageFlag` is being interpreted as a string as the last line always evaluates to `true` if `parameters.globalFlag` is `true`. Which is odd as if that line is just `myFlag: ${{ stageDef.stageFlag }}` it works as expected.

I can work around this by changing the line to

```
myFlag: ${{ and(parameters.globalFlag, eq(stageDef.stageFlag, 'true')) }}
```

This is pretty good and even works for `True` and `TRUE` as well as `true`. But it doesn't work for `Yes` or `On` which are also `true` in YAML. So it could easily trip up someone when they enter a true value and it doesn't work as expected.

How can I get the property `stageFlag` in my object type to be interpreted as a boolean? Is there a way to mark the type of a property within an object? Is there a way to cast a string to a boolean that handles all valid ways of entering a boolean value?

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to the fact that all YAML variables are stored as [string in an Azure DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#:%7E:text=All%20variables%20are%20stored%20as%20strings).

Your parameters on the other hand can [use different data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#parameter-data-types).
Despite that `globalFlag` is a boolean, the `stagesettings` is a YAML object so the  *all YAML variables are stored as a string* unfortunately applies here.

But as you discovered, using expressions like 'eq' can solve your issue a [bit through type casting the string in the expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#string-1).

I don't think there is another way with this object parameter, nor is there a way to define types to the variables.